# Getting "Bad Filename or Number" when renaming file with a variable for the destination filename

Tags: vbscript, windows-7-x64

I am trying to loop a folder full of .html files and add some code at the beginning of the files (although I am getting some unwanted line breaks before the code I am inserting) and also to grab the contents of the `<title>` tag and use this for the renaming each file.

I am replacing the spaces and unwanted characters with -'s

All of this works but I am also trying to rename the existing file (`Default0010.html` is one example) to the text from the `<title>`.

This works too but when I am trying to move the existing file to the new file I get a `Bad File name or Number` but when I explicilty set the destination file name to a simple string it works.

It makes me thing my string is not clean or you cannot use a variable for the destination.

Also please ignore the lines `Dim i`, `i = i + 1` and `If i=1 Then Exit For`.

This was added whilst I test the script then when  I was happy it does what I wanted I would run it on all the HTML files.

```
Set objFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set Folder = objFSO.GetFolder("C:\My Web Sites\test\www.test.org.uk\html")

Dim i

Dim ObjFsoFile
Dim ObjFile
Dim StrData
Dim StrTitleTag
Dim OldFilename
Dim NewFilename
Set ObjFsoFile = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'Loop all of the files
For Each File In Folder.Files
  'Get contents of the file and store in a string
  'Opening the file in READ mode
  Set ObjFile = ObjFsoFile.OpenTextFile(File.Name)

  'Reading from the file
  StrData = ObjFile.ReadAll
  'Add the Perch include to the beginning
  StrData = replace(StrData,"<?php include('cms/runtime.php');?>","") 'Remove the Perch include in-case we are re-running this
  StrData = replace(StrData,"<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC " & Chr(34) & "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" & Chr(34) & ">","<?php include('cms/runtime.php');?>" & vbcrlf & "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC " & Chr(34) & "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" & Chr(34) & ">")     
  'Msgbox StrData

  'Closing the file
  ObjFile.Close

  'Write the changes to the current file
  Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(File.Name,True)
  objFile.Write StrData
  objFile.Close

  'Re-write the contents of the current file and replace with the StrData Above

  'Grab the contents between <title> and </title>

  parse_string1 = StrData 'see above post 
  parse_string1 = replace(parse_string1,"<title>","¦") 
  parse_string = split(parse_string1,"¦") 
  parse = parse_string(1) 
  parse_string1 = replace(parse,"</title>","¦") 
  parse_string = split(parse_string1,"¦") 
  parsed_string = parse_string(0)

  StrTitleTag = parsed_string 'gives final result

  'Save old filename of current file to a string
  OldFilename = File.Name
  'Msgbox OldFilename

  'Rename current file to the above contents of between <title> and </title>
  'Replace spaces with - characters in the filename.

  Dim divider
  divider = "-"

  'Replace & with and
  NewFilename = Replace((StrTitleTag & ".php"),"&","and")
  'Replace triple space with single space     
  NewFilename = Replace(NewFilename,"   "," ")
  'Replace double space with single space
  NewFilename = Replace(NewFilename,"  "," ")
  'Replace - with space
  NewFilename = Replace(NewFilename," ",divider)
  'Replace ---- with -
  NewFilename = Replace(NewFilename,divider & "-" & divider,divider)      
  'Replace ---- with -
  NewFilename = Replace(NewFilename,divider & divider & divider,divider)          
  'Replace ,- with -
  NewFilename = Replace(NewFilename,"," & divider,divider)
  'Replace LineBreaks with nothing (remove line breaks)
  NewFilename = Replace(NewFilename,vbCrLf,"")    
  NewFilename = Replace(NewFilename,vbLf,"")  
  NewFilename = Replace(NewFilename,vbCr,"")  
  NewFilename = LCase(NewFilename)
  'Msgbox NewFilename

  'Loop through all files
  For Each File2 In Folder.Files
    'Opening the file in READ mode
    Set ObjFile = ObjFsoFile.OpenTextFile(File2.Name)

    'Get contents of the file and store in a string         
    'Reading from the file
    StrData = ObjFile.ReadAll

    'Closing the file
    ObjFile.Close

    'Replace all occurences of the old filename with the new filename
    StrData = Replace(StrData, OldFilename, NewFilename)

    'How to write file
    Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(File2.Name,True)
    objFile.Write StrData
    objFile.Close
  Next

  'Rename Old file with the new filename  
  If objFso.FileExists("C:\My Web Sites\test\www.test.org.uk\html\" & OldFilename) Then
    'NewFileName = "test.php"
    'NewFileName = "test-test-test-test-test-test-test-test-test.php"
    Msgbox "Renaming the file " & OldFilename & " (Length: " & Len(OldFilename)     & ") with the following name: " & NewFilename & " (Length: " & Len(NewFilename) & ")"
    Msgbox "Compare: test-test-test-test-test-test-test-test-test.php " & NewFilename
    objFso.MoveFile "C:\My Web   Sites\test\www.test.org.uk\html\" & OldFilename, "C:\My Web     Sites\test\www.test.org.uk\html\" & NewFileName
  End If

  i = i + 1
  If i=1 Then Exit For
Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't replace known bad characters. Replace everything that is **not** a **known good** character, e.g. by using a regular expression:

```
Set re = New RegExp
re.Pattern = "[^a-z0-9+._-]+"
re.Global  = True
re.IgnoreCase = True

NewFilename = re.Replace(OldFilename, "_")
```

The underscore (`_`) usually is a safe character for this kind of replacement.

Also, don't try to manually parse elements from an HTML file unless you have to. In your case the title can be extracted far easier, like this:

```
Set html = CreateObject("HTMLFile")
html.Write objFso.OpenTextFile(File.Name).ReadAll
title = html.Title
```

It will even collapse and trim whitespace for you.

And a file can be renamed by simply changing its `Name` property when you already have a handle to that file:

```
objFile.Name = NewFilename
```

Simplified version of your script (without those parts that modify the content of the files):

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

htmlFolder = "C:\My Web Sites\test\www.test.org.uk\html"

Set re = New RegExp
re.Pattern = "[^a-z0-9+._-]+"
re.Global  = True
re.IgnoreCase = True

For Each f In objFso.GetFolder(htmlFolder).Files
   data = f.OpenAsTextStream.ReadAll

   Set html = CreateObject("HTMLFile")
   html.Write data

   oldname = f.Name
   newname = re.Replace(f.Name, "_")

   f.Name = newname
Next
```

Comment: This looks great and I am trying out your suggestions now, once I am happy with them I will give you a nice big green tick! But also please note that I forgot to mention I need to loop through all of the file and replace any hyperlinks with the newfilename (this will update any links on the website to the new page)

Comment: I now get Object doesn't support this property or method: Code 800A01B6 `'Rename Old file with the new filename`
`If objFso.FileExists("C:\My Web Sites\Dodderhill\www.dodderhillhistory.org.uk\html\" & OldFilename) Then`
`Set ObjFile = ObjFsoFile.OpenTextFile(File.Name)`
`objFile.Name = NewFilename`
`'Closing the file`
`ObjFile.Close`
`End If`

Comment: You made `objFile` a [Text Stream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/312a5kbt) object, not a [File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ft05taf) object. Only the latter have a `Name` property. And it was already duly noted that you update the links in your files. Thus my remark that the simplified code did not include those parts (IOW you'd need to add them again). They were omitted from the sample code to keep the example simple.